# I don't want to add anything else under the child

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

I have a dynamic tree structure. I can add 3 elements to this tree structure called " Montaj, Kaynak, Parça and Sarf ".

**My Problem:** After adding the Parça And Sarf, nothing can be added under them. For example, everything can be added under *Montaj* and *Kaynak* , but once you add *Parça* or *Sarf*, nothing can be added under them.

How can I do it? ( Some terms are in Turkish. Don't mind ) My current code is the following

```
$(function() {
    a = 1;
    var jsondata = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "parent": "#",
            "text": "TEKLİF ADI"
        }
    ];

    createJSTree(jsondata);
});

function createJSTree(jsondata) {
    $('#agac').jstree({
        "core": {
            "check_callback": true,
            'data': jsondata,
        },
        "plugins": ["contextmenu", "state", "types"],
        "contextmenu": {
            "items": function($node) {
                var tree = $("#agac").jstree(true);
                return {
                    "EKLE": {
                        "separator_before": false,
                        "separator_after": true,
                        "label": "EKLE",
                        "action": false,
                        "submenu": {
                            "MONTAJ": {
                                "seperator_before": false,
                                "seperator_after": false,
                                "label": "MONTAJ",
                                action: function(obj) {
                                    $node = tree.create_node($node, {
                                        text: 'M0' + a++,
                                        type: 'folder'
                                    });
                                    tree.deselect_all();
                                    tree.select_node($node);
                                }
                            },
                            "KAYNAK": {
                                "seperator_before": false,
                                "seperator_after": false,
                                "label": "KAYNAK",
                                action: function(obj) {
                                    $node = tree.create_node($node, {
                                        text: 'K0' + a++,
                                        type: 'folder'
                                    });
                                    tree.deselect_all();
                                    tree.select_node($node);
                                }
                            },
                            "PARÇA": {
                                "disabled": true,
                                "seperator_before": false,
                                "seperator_after": false,
                                "label": "PARÇA",
                                action: function(obj) {
                                    $node = tree.create_node($node, {
                                        text: 'P0' + a++,
                                        type: 'file',
                                        icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-file'
                                    });
                                    tree.deselect_all();
                                    tree.select_node($node);
                                }
                            },
                            "SARF": {
                                "seperator_before": true,
                                "seperator_after": true,
                                "label": "SARF",
                                action: function(obj) {
                                    $node = tree.create_node($node, {
                                        text: 'S0' + a++,
                                        type: 'file',
                                        icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-file'
                                    });
                                    tree.deselect_all();
                                    tree.select_node($node);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "DEĞİŞTİR": {
                        "separator_before": false,
                        "separator_after": false,
                        "label": "DEĞİŞTİR",
                        "action": function(obj) {
                            tree.edit($node);
                        }
                    },
                    "KALDIR": {
                        "separator_before": false,
                        "separator_after": false,
                        "label": "KALDIR",
                        "action": function(obj) {
                            tree.delete_node($node);
                            a--;
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please remove all the blank lines... it's difficult enough to try and read your badly indented code as it is

Comment: @freefaller Yes I know. Happened by mistake, sorry

Comment: Sorry, but your question really isn't clear.  The subject says "I don't want to add anything else", but then your questions talks about being able to add some items, and not being able to add others, but it simply isn't clear what you actually want to happen. You need to make it very clear... what **should** it be doing, and what is it doing that it shouldn't be.  I've copied your code and I'm able to add as many items as I want without any restrictions

Comment: If I was going to make a guess, what I **think** you're asking for is that people should only be able to add new items within the `Montaj` and `Kaynak` folder items.  In other words they should be blocked from add any items to the `Parça` and `Sarf` items?

Comment: @freefaller Once you have added a PARÇA  or SARF item, them nothing should be added under it. Everything else can work as it is

Comment: @freefaller Do you understand me ?

Comment: Yes, just writing an answer for you

Comment: @freefaller Did you find the problem

Comment: More complicated than I thought, bear with me

Comment: @freefaller Okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to block people from creating any new nodes under the `Parça` and `Sarf` items, then only show the `EKLE` menu options when the user right-clicks on the nodes that you want them to be added to.

Firstly, you need to be able to distinguish between folder items and normal ones, which means you need to define your `types`...

```
"plugins": ["contextmenu", "state", "types"],
"types": { // ** NEW **
  "default": {},
  "folder": {}
},
"contextmenu": {
```

I have also assigned the `folder` type to your initial root object, which is necessary for the main part of the change...

```
var jsondata = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "TEKLİF ADI",
        "type": "folder" // ** NEW **
    }
];
```

The big change is making the context-menu only show what is necessary.

So instead of creating an object with all the options, I have created an empty object and add things as necessary.  In this case, if the `$node` you have clicked on has a type of `folder` you get the `EKLE` sub-menu... otherwise it's not visible.

(Without defining the `types` section of the config, the `$node.type` will **always** be `default`)

```
"items": function($node) {
    var tree = $("#agac").jstree(true);
    // ** NEW **
    var items = {};
    // Only show if a folder
    if ($node.type == "folder") {
        items["EKLE"] = {
            ...
        }
    }
    // Always show
    items["DEĞİŞTİR"] = {
        ...
    }
    items["KALDIR"] = {
        ...
    }
    return items;
}
```

To see a full working version, expand the following snippet...

```js
$(function() {
    a = 1;
    var jsondata = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "parent": "#",
            "text": "TEKLİF ADI",
            "type": "folder" // ** NEW **
        }
    ];

    createJSTree(jsondata);
});

function createJSTree(jsondata) {
    $('#agac').jstree({
        "core": {
            "check_callback": true,
            'data': jsondata,
        },
        "plugins": ["contextmenu", "state", "types"],
        "types": { // ** NEW **
          "default": {},
          "folder": {}
        },
        "contextmenu": {
            "items": function($node) {
                var tree = $("#agac").jstree(true);
                // ** NEW **
                var items = {};
                // Only show if a folder
                if ($node.type == "folder") {
                    items["EKLE"] = {
                        "separator_before": false,
                        "separator_after": true,
                        "label": "EKLE",
                        "action": false,
                        "submenu": {
                            "MONTAJ": {
                                "seperator_before": false,
                                "seperator_after": false,
                                "label": "MONTAJ",
                                action: function(obj) {
                                    $node = tree.create_node($node, {
                                        text: 'M0' + a++,
                                        type: 'folder'
                                    });
                                    tree.deselect_all();
                                    tree.select_node($node);
                                }
                            },
                            "KAYNAK": {
                                "seperator_before": false,
                                "seperator_after": false,
                                "label": "KAYNAK",
                                action: function(obj) {
                                    $node = tree.create_node($node, {
                                        text: 'K0' + a++,
                                        type: 'folder'
                                    });
                                    tree.deselect_all();
                                    tree.select_node($node);
                                }
                            },
                            "PARÇA": {
                                "disabled": true,
                                "seperator_before": false,
                                "seperator_after": false,
                                "label": "PARÇA",
                                action: function(obj) {
                                    $node = tree.create_node($node, {
                                        text: 'P0' + a++,
                                        type: 'file',
                                        icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-file'
                                    });
                                    tree.deselect_all();
                                    tree.select_node($node);
                                }
                            },
                            "SARF": {
                                "seperator_before": true,
                                "seperator_after": true,
                                "label": "SARF",
                                action: function(obj) {
                                    $node = tree.create_node($node, {
                                        text: 'S0' + a++,
                                        type: 'file',
                                        icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-file'
                                    });
                                    tree.deselect_all();
                                    tree.select_node($node);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Always show
                items["DEĞİŞTİR"] = {
                    "separator_before": false,
                    "separator_after": false,
                    "label": "DEĞİŞTİR",
                    "action": function(obj) {
                        tree.edit($node);
                    }
                }
                items["KALDIR"] = {
                    "separator_before": false,
                    "separator_after": false,
                    "label": "KALDIR",
                    "action": function(obj) {
                        tree.delete_node($node);
                        a--;
                    }
                }
                return items;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.8/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.8/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="agac"></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome - glad I could help.  Took a bit of working out! :-)